# Google map styles with ngx leaflet

Tags: angular, ngx-leaflet

I seem to have trouble using styles generated by google maps styling wizard with ngx-leaflet angular plugin. For an instance i used google maps styling wizard to reduce number of labels shown on the map.

Wanted to ask where in the code to apply given json object created by styling wizard.

i have following html:

```
<div leaflet 
 [leafletOptions]="options" 
 [leafletLayers]="layers" 
 [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl" 
 [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds" 
 (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

and this generated style:

```
 style = [
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Cant find it in documentation and tried in many  ways. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should provide some code to illustrate specifically what you're trying to do and show the issues you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a custom style for my map too but I didn't find a way to do it as easy as it can be done with Google Maps.
Neverthless, you could try some of the styles provided [here](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html).
In order to add the style you just need to add the layer to your map.

In your component class:

```
this.mapOptions = {
    layers: [
        tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
            { attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors' })
    ],
    ...
};
```

In your template:

```
<div style="height: 369px;" leaflet [leafletOptions]="mapOptions"></div>
```

The link gived as a parameter:

> https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png

in `tileLayer` corresponds to the `CartoDB.Voyager` chosen style.

I hope this alternative could be useful.